# fs.writeFile does not resolve

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, fs, electron-vue

I'm trying to save an image from a canvas to a file on disk with fs in an Electron app. I'm using async/await but as soon as the function gets called, I see the file gets created but no data is written to it until I refresh the page. The line `console.log('Saved')` doesn't execute until the refresh.

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
  async capture() {
    this.canvas = this.$refs.canvas;
    const context = this.canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, 1280, 720);
    const image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");


    const data = image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
    const buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
    try {

      await fs.writeFile(`${this.prescriptionId}.png`,buf);
      console.log('Saved')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }

  },
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help? No errors get logged using `node v12.16.1`

Update: 
If I use `fs.writeFileSync` I get an error:

```
TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.promises.writeFileSync is not a function
    at VueComponent._callee4$ (MainPage.vue?23fd:369)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:62)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:296)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:114)
    at step (asyncToGenerator.js?0f75:17)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?0f75:35)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (_export.js?63b6:36)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?0f75:14)
    at VueComponent.capture (MainPage.vue?23fd:359)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
const context = 
this.canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, 1280, 720);
 const image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

const data = image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
const buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
 (async () => {
 try {
   await fs.writeFile(`${this.prescriptionId}.png`,buf);
 console.log('Saved')
 } catch (error) {
 console.log(error)
}
)(this);
```

Comment: The function is already defined as ```async```. I've updated the question

Comment: the problem is because this call is async and probably is loosing the context right after, I was able to fix it on my end by using fs.writeFileSync which does it synchronously. hope this helps

Comment: Using ```fs.writeFileSync``` gives me an error. I've updated the question to include it. Even so I would prefer to keep using async await if possible

Comment: You can try this one

[browserify-fs](https://github.com/mafintosh/browserify-fs)